# replace and combine arrays

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I'm trying to combine 2 arrays and replace the the $x array cells with the $y cells.
I have this code:

```
<?php

$x = array (
        'a'  => '1',
        'b'  => '2',
        'd'  => '6'
    );

$y = array (
        'a'  => '3',
        'b'  => '4',
        'c'  => '5'
    );
```

how can I get an array like this:

```
a => 3,
b => 4,
c => 5,
d => 6
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: `array_merge` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Note: array_merge will append arrays with numeric keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

```
$z = array_merge($x, $y);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 3
    [b] => 4
    [d] => 6
    [c] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and make sure you put the array that you want to override first.
So in your case since you want `$y` to overrride `$x` use: `array_merge($x,$y);`